# How can I find out the current exchange rate of Bitcoin/USD?

Tags: exchange-rate, buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins

What is the value of 1 bitcoin in USD, today? Where can the exchange rate be looked up?

Comment: 1$ = 0.002654111417556237btc, Source=First result on google "1 Dollar to Bitcoin"
1btc = 376.77$

Comment: Question and answer pairs on SE should aim to be relevant for a longer period of time. The answer giving the current figures would be outdated within the hour. Therefore, I've changed the question to ask how to generally solve this question, instead of asking for the current figures. --- **To my knowledge we actually haven't decided on a canonical question that gives help on finding the current exchange rates of Bitcoin.** If you have good suggestions for a canonical Q&A pair that answers this topic, please provide it in a comment or as a "duplicate vote target".

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Bitcoin spot price and how is it calculated?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/13255/5406), [Calculating the current price of 1 BTC?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9492/5406)

Comment: @GordonAmable: Please don't use comments to answer the question. Please write an answer post instead.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple. Go to google and type: BTC to USD

A nice box with the current exchange rate should appear on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The price is constantly changing so this answer will vary quite a bit even within a day.

At time of writing (Nov 2015) the price is $375.40 per 1 bitcoin.

$1.00 should be ~0.0027 bitcoin.

You can check price at anytime by going to:
http://www.coindesk.com/price/

Price per USA dollar in bitcoin would just be ~ (1 / bitcoin price).

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is Tradeblock markets, shows live rates for various exchanges, and converted to USD

https://tradeblock.com/markets

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Programatically using CoinDesk price index API http://www.coindesk.com/api/
for example
https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json